# set catalina opts in tomcat configuration

Tags: tomcat

Hi i set parameters for tomcat in configuration window on tab java and field java options. I'd like add to configuration to catalina_opts is there a way how to do it??

In that field i have

```
-Dcatalina.home=d:\apache-tomcat-7.0.23
-Dcatalina.base=d:\apache-tomcat-7.0.23
-Djava.endorsed=d:\apache-tomcat-7.0.23\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=d:\apache-tomcat-7.0.23\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=d:\apache-tomcat-7.0.23\conf\logging.properties
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Edit: 22.06.2012 12:26

I want add this parameters

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8777 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.1.1
```

Edit: 22.06.2012 12:51

I put these parameters directly into the field "Java options" and it works, not sure why it didn't work the 1st time.

Comment: If you're running linux, it's probably better to set the -D options in /etc/sysconfig/tomcat6. That way you can pass different options to different tomcats running on the same box. More info here (for instance): http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188102/How-to-Run-Multiple-Instances-of-Tomcat-on-a-Single-Server

Comment: This probably isn't distribution-independent, though. Or the right version of tomcat, for that matter. I found my `JAVA_OPTS=` **on Ubuntu 12.04** (installed tomcat7 from repo) in `/etc/default/tomcat7`. just to note.

Comment: If you are running as a Windows service, CATALINA_OPTS is going to be ignored. You will have to switch to command-line usage or continue to use the configuration window's Java tab.

Answer (score 26):

Place the following in `catalina.sh` (below the documentation)

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dfoo=foo -Dbar=bar"
```

Comment: is it okay to put it at the bottom of catalina.sh?

Comment: He uses windows so he needs to change it in catalina.bat

Comment: move that in the setenv file which are meant to hold such configuration

Comment: setenv was introduced with TC8 and is not available in TC7

Comment: you should add that inside the setenv.sh script 
 
    echo -e "\nCATALINA_OPTS=\"-Dspring.profiles.active=dev\"" >> ${CATALINA_BASE}/bin/setenv.sh

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use Tomcat as Windows Service, just ignore editing `catalina.bat` (also `CATALONA_OPTS` or `JAVA_OPTS`).
After that you install Tomcat as WS, just use `++JvmOptions="<JvmOptions>"`(you should be in tomcat_home/bat directory)
e.g.

```
tomcat8.exe //US/Tomcat_Service ++JvmOptions="-D<option>"
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatly if you run it a as a service it won't use the parameters. Use this [doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html) to update the --JvmOptions parameter or edit it directly executing the following command from CATALINA_HOME/bin/

```
tomcat7w //ES/myServiceName
```

If you use tomcat .bat scripts I would create the [enviroment variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) **CATALINA_OPTS** with all thouse options as a value. The initial script *startup.bat* will call *catalina.bat* which will execute something like this depending on the Tomcat version:

```
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %JPDA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% [...]
```

This way you do not need to modify the tomcat Script and new versions of Tomcat will read this enviroment variable if you make an update, lets say, to Tomcat 8.

Answer (score 3):

With Tomcat as Windows service, I found the registry keys you can change to edit Java Options. In my case, it fixed my problem.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Procrun 2.0\[service name]\Parameters\Java

Here you can find [examples](https://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/Run-Java-Program-as-a-Windows-Service-With-Procrun) and [references](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html).

Answer (score 0):

See here:
http://www.springwebdevelopment.com/tomcat-more-memory-catalina_opts

Just in case the link won't work anymore:

On Windows
Edit the file $TOMCAT_HOME\bin\startup.bat and insert or alter the following line, substituting for the desired values:
set CATALINA_OPTS=...

On Linux
Edit the file $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/startup.sh and insert the following line, substituting for the desired value, eg. Bash Shell:
export CATALINA_OPTS=...
The line you add should go just before the line starting exec “$PRGDIR…

Mihai

Comment: I read somewhere when i set more parameters must use CATALINA_OPTS = $CATALINA_OPTS + NewOne    and is'n better put it into catalina.bat??

Comment: startup.bat executes catalina.bat so I would rather put CATALINA_OPTS in there.

Comment: Modded-down because Tomcat's startup scripts are *not* used when launching Tomcat as a Windows Service: editing these scripts is a waste of time. Additionally, customization of `catalina.bat` and `startup.bat` (as the OP is obviously on Windows) is discouraged. Instead, use `setenv.bat` in the `bin/` directory (you may have to create the file because Tomcat does not ship with one) to customize your environment... but ***only*** if you are launching using scripts: Windows Services, again, completely ignore these files.